# Show that the equation $2-x=\frac{lnx}{4}$ has a unique root in the interval 0<x<$\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$Show \quad that\quad  the \quad equation \quad 2 - x = \frac{lnx}{4}\quad  has \quad a \quad unique \quad root \quad x=\eta \quad in\quad  the \quad interval \quad 0<x<\infty$.

-from Martin Braun's Differential equations and their applications p.87.

---

I tried to solve this problem with the theorem that

**if f(x) and f'(x) are continuous in the interval [a,b], with |f'(x)|≤$\lambda$<1, and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ all lie in the interval [a,b], then the iterates $x_n$ converges to a unique number $\eta$ satisfying $\eta$=f($\eta$).**

But, $f(x) = 2 - \frac{lnx}{4}$, obtained from $ x = 2 - \frac{lnx}{4}$, has derivative $f'(x) = \frac 1 {4x}$. And, obviously, $|f'(x)|≥1$ when $0<x≤\frac 1 4$. Hence, it seems that the theorem couldn't be applied, and this is where I stuck.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what the graphs of these functions look like? If not try wikipedia or a graphing calculator.

Now, notice that $\operatorname{ln}x$ increases from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. The other function only decreases though... If two cars are going opposite direction and they never change course, how many times will they meet?

The theorem that you are mentioning doesn't really fit here. For that matter it is more advanced than the context of the problem...

Comment: Many thanks!! Seems I was obsessed with using the theorems..